# How to sort a primeng datatable programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to be able to trigger a sort event in a p-dataTable component from its parent component. This kind of violates the "data down, actions up" principle that has guided modern web development, but I have a separate component that users will click on to trigger sorting in the primeng table, and I don't see another way to trigger this in the dataTable component API.

Comment: I am not sure if sortable='custom' is what you want? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gridObject.sortColumn = gridObject.columns.find(col => col.field === paginationOptions.SortColumn);
gridObject.sortField = paginationOptions.SortColumn;
gridObject.sortOrder = (paginationOptions.SortOrder == "ASC" ? 1 : -1);
gridObject.sortSingle();
```

`gridObject`: it's my Datatable
`paginationOptions`: it's pagination option, like sort column and sort order.
`1` is used for ascending and `-1` is used for descending.

Above 4 statement will execute the sort action.

Comment: sortColumn is not needed as of PrimeNG 12